# Find value from given quadratic equation.

Tags: quadratics, real-numbers

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are real numbers with $ab \neq 0$ and the equation $120a^{2}-120a+1=0$ and $b^{2}-120b+120=0$ hold. Find the value of $\dfrac{1+b+ab}{a}$.

I can solve this problem by putting values of $a$ and $b$ from $120a^{2}-120a+1=0$ and $b^{2}-120b+120=0$ in $\dfrac{1+b+ab}{a}$, but I need some shortcut or easy methos of solve instead of just putting the values obtain.

Comment: can I have reasons for the downvote, please?

Comment: solve the quadratic equations

Comment: You are likely to get down-votes if you don't give us any information why this should be interesting, where you saw it, or came up with it, or where you are stuck.  You will particularly get down votes if it appears that you are using this community to do your homework for you.  We are glad to help, but we want to see some effort and get you through your sticking points.  So, where are you suck?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner but this problem is of only 3 marks, and putting the value of $a$ and $b$ in $\dfrac{1+b+ab}{a}$ will be tedious, I'm looking for any shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint :

$$120a^2-120a+1=0\iff \left(\frac 1a\right)^2-120\cdot \frac 1a+120=0$$
Hence, $b,\frac 1a$ are the solutions of 
$$t^2-120t+120=0$$

Comment: you did what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the first equation:

$120a^2 - 120a + 1 =0 \Rightarrow a = \frac{1}{60} (30 \pm \sqrt{870})$

From the second equation:

$b^2 - 120b + 120 = 0 \Rightarrow b = 2 \left(30 \pm \sqrt{870}\right)$,

just by using the quadratic formula.

Then, you have four possible answers for: $(1 + b + ab) / ab$ given these possible pairings of $a$ and $b$ above.